I am unable to use Selenium to open a specific chrome profile
I wanted to use Selenium to open a Chrome profile, Profile 3. I have tried many things with the help of GPT and whatever made sense to me. But so far, I am unable to get it done.
It seems to work well if I don't involve a Chrome profile. However, when I specified a chrome profile, it threw me a few different errors. I handled most of the errors by adding different arguments. But I am still stuck at: The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.
Let me share the code snippet I am using:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()

# Specify the path to your user profile directory
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 3")

# Additional options to prevent crashing
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

# Path to ChromeDriver
service = Service(r"C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe")

# Initialize the WebDriver with the options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Set timeouts
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

# Go to a specific URL
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

Please note that I have also tried to close all the instances of the Chrome browser. I have also reinstalled my web driver as well. These were the recommendations I found from similar questions here.
Is there anything I am missing out in this code?
Thanks.

Add Profile 3 to the location path as below:
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3")
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 3")


Doing so has opened the general browser, not the one with the 'Profile 3'.
